# Check if Dropzone is already attached

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

There are few dropzones on a page and new items are loaded by ajax, so **I need to check, if dropzone already attached on that item**.

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;


    function initDropzones()
    {

        $('.dropzones').each(function () {

            // how to check dropzone exists on item?
            // or how to destroy already existed dropzone (so reinitialize after)

            $(this).dropzone({
                url: ...
            })
        });
    }

    someAjaxAdd() {
        // add new elements and with new one dropzone
        initDropzones();
    }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I solve it with try catch, but I will be glad if someone offer better solution

Comment: You want to know if there is files in your dropzone ?

Comment: No, I want to know if dropzone is initialized on the element. Sorry for bad formulation

Comment: Have you seen this init function in the doc ? http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-init

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to check the dropzone attribute and if it exists you can destroy it:

```
function initDropzones() {
    $('.dropzone').each(function () {

        let dropzoneControl = $(this)[0].dropzone;
        if (dropzoneControl) {
            dropzoneControl.destroy();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can check like `dropzoneControl == undefined`